# Celery rate-limiting: Is it possible to rate-limit a celery task differently based on a run-time parameter?

Tags: django, redis, queue, celery, message-queue

I would like to rate-limit a Celery task based on certain parameters that are decided at runtime. Eg: If the parameter is 1, the rate limit might be 100. If the parameter is 2, the rate-limit might be 25. Moreover, I would like to be able to modify these rate-limits at run-time.

Does celery provide a way of doing this? I could use a routing_key to send tasks to different queues based on a parameter, but celery doesn't appear to support queue-level rate-limiting.

One possible solution would be to use `eta` while queueing up the task, but I was wondering if there was a better way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Celery provides a built-in rate limit system, but it doesn't work the way most people expect a rate limit system to work and it has several limitations. I implemented a distributed rate limiting system based on the ETA like you mentioned and some Lua scripts on Redis, it worked quite well so I would recommend that approach.

This article details an approach similar to that one:

https://callhub.io/distributed-rate-limiting-with-redis-and-celery/

I used a way simpler version, my lua script was just this:

```
local current_time = tonumber(ARGV[1])
local eta = tonumber(redis.call('get', KEYS[1]))
local interval = tonumber(ARGV[2])

if not eta or eta < current_time then
    redis.call('set', KEYS[1], current_time + interval, 'EX', 10800)
    return nil
else
    redis.call('set', KEYS[1], eta + interval, 'EX', 10800)
    return tostring(eta)
end
```

And I had to simple override the task `apply_async` method and call that lua script with the delay that I wanted:

```
def apply_async(self, *args, **kwargs):
    now = int(time.time())

    # From django-redis
    conn = get_redis_connection('default')

    cache_key = 'something'

    eta = conn.eval(self.rate_limit_script, 1, cache_key, now, rate_limiter.get_delay())

    if eta:
        eta = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(eta), tz=timezone.get_current_timezone())
        kwargs['eta'] = eta
    return super().apply_async(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update the rate_limit at runtime within the part of your application that has access to the Celery app instance via `celery_app.control.rate_limit()`.

**./task.py**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery("sample")

app.conf.update(
    broker_url='amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672',
    task_annotations={
        'task.func1': {
            'rate_limit': '10/s'  # Default is 10 per second
        }
    },
)


@app.task
def func1(ctr):
    print(f"I have now processed task {ctr}")
```

**./runner.py**

```
import task

print(f"Current rate_limit is 10/s")

for ctr in range(7):
    print(f"Enqueue task {ctr}")
    task.func1.delay(ctr)

    if ctr == 3:
        choice = input("Let's update the rate limit setting [1/2]: ")
        if choice == "1":
            new_rate_limit = '1/m'
            print(f"Changing rate_limit to {new_rate_limit}")
            task.app.control.rate_limit('task.func1', new_rate_limit)
        elif choice == "2":
            new_rate_limit = '1/h'
            print(f"Changing rate_limit to {new_rate_limit}")
            task.app.control.rate_limit('task.func1', new_rate_limit)
        else:
            print("Retaining default rate_limit")
```

- For simplicity of example, here we have a raw python runnable script that acts as the caller to our celery task. In real life applications, this could be a Django view integrated with celery, or whatever.

Execute the task listener (the **consumer**):

```
$ celery --app=task worker --loglevel=INFO
```

Execute the task caller (the **producer**):

```
$ python3 runner.py 
Current rate_limit is 10/s
Enqueue task 0
Enqueue task 1
Enqueue task 2
Enqueue task 3
Let's update the rate limit setting [1/2]: 1
Changing rate_limit to 1/m
Enqueue task 4
Enqueue task 5
Enqueue task 6
```

- Here, we can see that the first 4 runs have a rate of 10 per second. Then with a runtime input, we updated it to 1 per minute for the remaining 3 runs.

Logs of the task listener (the **consumer**):

```
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,006: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: task.func1[60600074-16ad-41b1-afbf-7a89da5af2f0]  
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,007: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: task.func1[e93f9936-4d56-49a7-bb8b-757817235aa2]  
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,007: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] I have now processed task 0
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,008: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task task.func1[60600074-16ad-41b1-afbf-7a89da5af2f0] succeeded in 0.000337354000293999s: None
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,010: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: task.func1[c0c369c4-dbcf-43db-b79c-49d5866b136f]  
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,010: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: task.func1[38b32102-7313-4e64-be77-f9565ce04683]  
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,217: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] I have now processed task 2
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,218: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task task.func1[c0c369c4-dbcf-43db-b79c-49d5866b136f] succeeded in 0.0006413599985535257s: None
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,217: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] I have now processed task 1
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,219: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task task.func1[e93f9936-4d56-49a7-bb8b-757817235aa2] succeeded in 0.0021943179999652784s: None
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,726: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] I have now processed task 3
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,727: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task task.func1[38b32102-7313-4e64-be77-f9565ce04683] succeeded in 0.00125738899987482s: None
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,809: INFO/MainProcess] New rate limit for tasks of type task.func1: 1/m.
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,810: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: task.func1[1acb9b7e-755e-4773-a3db-0a284c7024bb]  
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,811: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: task.func1[b861a33a-0856-4044-a498-250c0da48d53]  
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,811: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] I have now processed task 4
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,812: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task task.func1[1acb9b7e-755e-4773-a3db-0a284c7024bb] succeeded in 0.0006612189990846673s: None
[2021-04-30 10:35:44,812: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: task.func1[e2e79f75-7628-4449-b880-e3a03020da7e]  
[2021-04-30 10:36:44,892: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] I have now processed task 5
[2021-04-30 10:36:44,892: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task task.func1[b861a33a-0856-4044-a498-250c0da48d53] succeeded in 0.00017851099983090535s: None
[2021-04-30 10:37:44,830: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] I have now processed task 6
[2021-04-30 10:37:44,831: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task task.func1[e2e79f75-7628-4449-b880-e3a03020da7e] succeeded in 0.0007846450007491512s: None
```

- Here, you could see that the first 4 tasks (with a rate of 10 per second) are all processed at 10:35:44 while the other 3 tasks (with the updated rate of 1 per minute) are processed at 10:35:44, 10:36:44, and 10:37:44 respectively.

Reference: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#changing-rate-limits-at-run-time